# Detecting when a Process (GUI) is "Done" even though it doesn't Exit?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I'm writing a console app that detects USB drives, formats them, and then runs a program called [UnetBootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/) to write an ISO to the drives. Everything works fine, but the issue is UNetbootin doesn't simply "exit" so `.WaitForExit()` doesn't work unless the user clicks the "Exit" button.

The only way I can imagine to solve this is either by checking for that button to appear or trying to guess if the process is idling somehow. In either case, I wouldn't know where to start.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is going to be ugly no matter how you slice it. I 'm not aware of a better approach, so here is one that would work AFAIK:

1. Get the PID of your target process (you already have that if you can call `WaitForExit`)
2. Get [handles to all windows of that process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2238609/c-sharp-get-handles-to-all-windows-of-a-process)
3. Use `GetWindowText` to [get the text of each and every window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5440629/why-does-getwindowtext-hang-with-a-closed-handle-but-not-with-a-random-one) from step 2
4. If any window has text equal to "Reboot Now", you know you 're done

**WARNING:** At this point I should mention that `GetWindowText` should be considered extremely dangerous because it can do evil things to your thread, including hanging it, due to no fault of your own. *In practice* it won't happen, but it's something you should know.