# Get around disabled selection

Tags: c#

I have a program that displays information(simple text, but not in a txt box, looks like labels in .NET) but has disabled selection and disabled left and right mouse click.

I want to write another program(lets say in C#, but it can be other language also) that acts as a user and writes down the info displayed by the first program in a txt file.

Is there a way that i can get around disabled selection, left and right mouse click?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`GetWindowText` windows API is your friend:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "GetWindowText", ExactSpelling = false, CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
private static extern int GetWindowText(IntPtr hWnd, StringBuilder lpWindowText, int nMaxCount);
```

you would have to get the handle of the other program's window then loop on all child windows/controls using `EnumChildWindows` then get the text calling `GetWindowText` against all those handles. In some cases you would not get a result as expected I guess or could be that some controls have no handle exposed.

```
[DllImport("user32")]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
public static extern bool EnumChildWindows(IntPtr window, EnumWindowProc callback, IntPtr i);
```

for details and answers on how to use `EnumChildWindows` see here:

[Why is EnumChildWindows skipping children?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7014190/why-is-enumchildwindows-skipping-children)

have also a look here for some ideas and examples... [Why does GetWindowText hang with a "closed" handle but not with a random one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5440629/why-does-getwindowtext-hang-with-a-closed-handle-but-not-with-a-random-one)